# Is it possible to push the "content" from a ":before" css pseudo-element out of container?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to make the "and commented:" appear (when there's a comment, obviously) inline  after objectname without adding more classes or wrapper elements?  I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.  I can do it by adding a wrapper to the comment but it's not pretty.

NOT WORKING:

```
.username, .objectname { font-weight:bold; }

    .objectname:before {content: "'"; }
    .objectname:after { content: "'"; }

    .comment { font-style: italic; display: block; margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; background-color: pink; }
    .comment:before {content: "and commented:"; display:inline; background-color: purple;}

    .eventtime { display: block; background-color: yellowgreen;margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; color: #A1A1A0; }
 <div class="item">
    <span class="username">Some Person</span>
    completed the task
    <span class="objectname">A Random Task</span>
    <span class="comment">silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly</span>
    <span class="eventtime">Today @ 12:37PM</span>
</div>
```

WORKING:

```
        .username, .objectname { font-weight: bold; }
    .objectname:before {content: "'";}
    .objectname:after { content: "'"; }
    .comment { font-style: italic; display: block;margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; background-color: pink;color: #919190;}
    .commentwrapper:before {content: "and commented:"; display:inline; background-color: purple;}
    .eventtime { display: block; background-color: yellowgreen;margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; color: #A1A1A0; }
     <div id="item1" class="item">
    <span class="username">Some Person</span>
    completed the task
    <span class="objectname">A Random Task</span>
    <span class="commentwrapper">
        <span class="comment">silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment silly comment</span>
    </span>
    <span class="eventtime">Today @ 12:37PM</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste a sample on jsFiddle.net

Comment: Is a `comment` wrapper generated if there is no comment?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have two different `display` settings (`inline` and `block`), one for the parent and one for the pseudo-element (that will behave like two separate elements). But you can fake it and push the pseudo-element outside of the parent and onto the line above it (well actually, push the comment below it).

The trick is to use `:before` to insert a newline (`\a`) and `white-space: pre` to make it show. Then use `:after` for the "and commented" part. Set the parent to `position: relative;` and `:after` to `position: absolute`. Use `padding-left` on the parent to make enough room for `:after` and then position `:after` with `left: 0` and `top: 0`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image]

#### CSS:

```css
.comment {
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 3px 0 3px 0;
    padding-left: 110px;
    position: relative;
}

.comment:after {
    background-color: purple;
    content: "and commented:";
    left: 0;
    padding-right: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.comment:before {
    content: '\a';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Based on his original "working" code, I believe the OP wants the pink area to be `display: block` and sit below where "and commented" is at. However, only he can answer that for sure. If _not_, your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

If you do NOT generate a `span` when there is no comments, then a CSS3 solution is as follows:

[**See fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vybKu/5/). Note, I had to remove the bold from the single quotes around the task, else it made the "and commented" bold also.

```
.username, .objectname { font-weight: bold; }
.objectname:before {content: "'"; font-weight: normal;}
.objectname:after { content: "'"; font-weight: normal;}
.objectname:nth-last-child(3):after { /*<-- only targeted if a comment generated */
   content: "' and commented";
 } 
.comment { 
   font-style: italic; 
   display: block;
   margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; 
   background-color: pink;
   color: #919190;
}
.eventtime { display: block; background-color: yellowgreen;margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
```

[My orignial idea](http://jsfiddle.net/vybKu/4/), now the optional solution (see comments below for why the change):

```
.objectname:nth-last-of-type(3):after { /*<-- only targeted if a comment generated */
   content: "' and commented";
 }
```

Comment: You'll want to use `:nth-last-child(3)` instead of `:nth-last-of-type(3)` to prevent confusion between the two pseudo-classes when used without a type selector.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not sure I follow you. The four elements in the html nested in his item are all `spans`. I don't see how the `:nth-last-of-type` would be confused by pseudo-classes, when it is being used on the `.objectname` which is a `span` element. Can you clarify?

Comment: With the given HTML both will work the same, but what I'm saying is that the nature of `:*-of-type` pseudo-classes makes it easy to get confused when you're looking at the stylesheet - `.objectname:nth-last-of-type(3)` can easily be misinterpreted by some as "the 3rd last `.objectname`" rather than "an element that's the 3rd last of its type and has the class `.objectname`". If the author knows what he's doing, then either one will work, but `:*-of-type()` without a type selector can be confusing and error-prone - especially when you begin to alter the markup.

Comment: @BoltClock: Okay, you were talking inexperienced "author" confusion. That makes sense, because I was saying to myself that they are the same in this case, and has nothing to do with the pseudo-elements. I can see your logic.